# Karnaugh map for 3 variables

Tags: karnaugh-map

I am trying to create a binary adder. I have this truth table:

[image]

This is the Karnaugh map that I made for this function (see that there is a mistake: instead of c, it had to be "c-in"):

[image]

Now, as the map looks like that, it gives me that `s = c + c` but that is certainly false. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Erm, I see a^b^c...

Comment: yeah, you-re right. that's how I found it on the website, but I don't know how to get it. please, post an answer with the explanation. I am student, and I haven't been working with this for a long time

Comment: How did you draw the Karnaugh maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the top left corner, where a=0 and c=0, we see that s follows b. This gives us a partial result of *s=b*. Moving down to the bottom left corner, we see that s is inverted when a=1. This is the XOR operation, and gives us *s=a^b*. Moving over to the right side, we see that the output is inverted when c=1. This gives us our final result of **s=a^b^c**.

Answer (score 1):

Karnaugh maps are usually drawn in Grey Code (with one bit changing at a time, so 000, 001, 011, 010 rather than with decimal sequence*) and if you do that, you get:
[image].

This corresponds to minterms

> C'A'B + C'AB' + CA'B' + CAB = C' (A'B + AB') + C(A'B' + AB)
>   The XOR function is A ^B=A'B + AB' and A XNOR B is A'B' + AB
>   So f= C'(A XOR B) + C (A XNOR B) = C' (A XOR B) + C(A XOR B)' = C XOR (A XOR B) = A XOR B XOR C

- Note: You can only group together cells and reduce using a K-Map when it is in Grey Code sequence, because grouping two elements together (and discarding the variable that changes) correspons to `BC(A + A') = BC` which only makes sense when one bit is changing.